# Can this matrix equation be resolved?

Tags: matrices

Studying matrix equations I came to this equation:
$$
X * A * X^{-1} = B
$$
where A, B are known and invertible and X is desired.

Can this equation be resolved and how many solutions does it have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ exists, then $A$ and $B$ are said to be "similar". A minority of matrix pairs are similar. If they are similar, then $X$ is known as a "change of basis" matrix. $X$ is not unique: clearly if $X$ is a solution then $cX$ is as well, for any non-zero scalar $c$. Also, if we have $A=YAY^{-1}$ for any $Y$, then $(XY)A(XY)^{-1}=B$, $ZXY$ is also a solution. $A=YAY^{-1}$ is equivalent to $AY = YA$, which is the condition that $A$ and $Y$ commute. So we can say that given any solution $X$, $XY$ is a solution for any $Y$ that commutes with $A$.

So:

existence: $A$ and $B$ are similar

uniqueness: up to matrices that commute with $A$.

Answer (score 1):

In general, it cannot be solved. For instance, it has no solution of the characteristic polynomials of $A$ and $B$ are distinct. Actually, it can be solved if and only if $A$ and $B$ have the same Jordan normal forms.